# Como recarregar uma página PHP via Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, json

Eu possuo uma página em PHP e que grava os dodos de um formulário via JSON, abaixo o script:

Index.php

```
<?php
  include '../includes/config_db.php';
  include '../includes/functions.php';
  include 'pdv_lib.php';

  class Conta {
   public $mesaNumero;
   public $id;
   public $referenciaId;
   public $status;
  }

  $id_estabelecimento = addslashes($_REQUEST['estabelecimento']);
  $mac        = addslashes($_REQUEST['mac']);

  $conn = conectar_pdv();
  $conta = get_conta($conn, $mac, $link, $id_estabelecimento);
 ?>
```

pdv_lib.php

```
<?php
  function get_conta($conexao_pdv, $mac, $conexao_portal, $estabelecimento_id)  {
    $conta = new Conta();

    echo "Mac = $mac, Estabelecimento = $estabelecimento_id<br>"; 
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($conta);
    echo '</pre>';

    $query_cliente_conta = "SELECT referencia_conta_id, conta_id FROM clientes_contas where mac = '$mac' and estabelecimento_id = $estabelecimento_id order by modified desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao_portal, $query_cliente_conta);
    $db_conta = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $conta->referenciaId = $db_conta['referencia_conta_id'];
    $conta->id = $db_conta['conta_id'];

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($conta);
    echo '</pre>';

    return $conta;
  }
?>
```

```js
    function gravar_conta(mac, mesa_numero, estabelecimento_id, nome_conta)  {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gravar_conta.php?mac=" + mac + '&mesa_numero=' + mesa_numero + '&estabelecimento_id=' + estabelecimento_id + '&nome_conta=' + nome_conta,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
        }
      });

      location.href = "index.php?estabelecimento=" + estabelecimento_id + "&mac=" + mac;
    }
```

A código funciona corretamente. Os dados são gravados no meu banco de dados e em seguida a página é recarregada passando para ela mesma dois parâmetros, esses dois parâmetros serão consultados no meu banco de dados via PHP. O problema é que esses dados recém gravados não são encontrados na minha base de dados após eu recarregar a página via Javascript. Detalhe:

- Se eu der um refresh via teclado a página então encontra esses dados.
- Se eu trocar os valores por dados que aviam sido gravados anteriormente a página recarrega reconhecendo esses registros, o problema aparentemente é que minha página PHP não encontra oque eu acabei de gravar via JSON.

Comment: Tentou usar o location.href dentro da callback de success? Se puder postar o php que faz a consulta, pode tambem ser algo relacionado ao cache do navegador/página

Comment: Se eu colocar dentro do success o callback não funciona.

Comment: Se não entra no success então tem algo errado gravar_conta.php, pega um retorno do php no success e debuga por partes o código. Se puder posta o gravar_conta na questão.

Comment: Não entra no success porque o gravar_conta.php não retorna um json, eu apenas faço inserções não tenho porque retornar algo de volta. Se tivesse algum erro nem gravaria. Mas vou postar o php resumido.

Comment: O correto é colocar dentro do método `success` mesmo, pois você pode ser redirecionado antes de completar a requisição do *AJAX*.

Comment: É isso mesmo Paulo, obrigado!

Comment: Na verdade o correto, corretíssimo (rs) já que `$.ajax` implementa a "interface" dos Deferred Objects seria colocar no [jQuery.done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)